# Rerun & End program

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to get this C++ program to work so that the program reruns itself when 'y' is entered and when 'n' is entered, it stops running and just asks the user to enter any key to end it. It is not working since it just keeps on running even when 'n' is entered.
What I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
// variables
int width;
int length;
    char again; // to hold y or n input

cout << "Enter length of rectangle";
cin >> length;
cout << "Enter width of rectangle";
cin >> width;
cout << "The area of the rectangle is" << length * width;
cout << "The perimeter of the rectangle is" (length  * length) * (width * width);

    // Asks user if they want to play again
       cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
       cin >> again;
    } else if (again == 'n') {
      cout << "Press any key to continue." << endl;
      cin.ignore(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make something run again you need a *loop*, your code doesn't have a loop. You can't just ask the user question and expect the compiler to know what to do.

Comment: And as usual 'it's not working' is an incredibly unhelpful thing to say. Tell us what actually happens when you run your code.

Comment: it keeps on running even when 'n' is entered. It should print out the "press any key to continue" and then when a key is pressed then it should continue again. @john

Comment: You check `answer` *before* initialize it with user input... logic is incorrect (and it is UB).

Answer (score 0):

So here is the mistake, you test the variable `again` before you ask the question. Obviously you should test the variable **after** you ask the question.

Also you need to use `ignore` after you get the reply to the question, because there will still be input in the buffer.

```
char again; // to hold y or n input

// Asks user if they want to play again
cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
cin >> again;
// ignore any remaining input
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
if (again == 'y'){
    ...
} else if (again == 'n') {
  cout << "Press any key to continue." << endl;
  cin.ignore(1);
}
```

I have a feeling however that the code you posted is not the real code, so if this doesn't make sense, post some more code.

Comment: The code is very long, that's why I only posted part of it @John

Comment: @randomp103 Well hopefully the code above will help, you got the order of things wrong in the posted code, and you failed to use ignore when it was needed.

Comment: I was able to figure it out for the longer program but for this one that is so simple, it just doesn't do anything when I enter y or n. I am going to edit my post and show the full code for that one @John

Comment: @randomp103 Your editted code doesn't compile, there's an `else if` without any `if`. Please make sure you are posting the genuine code.

Comment: @randomp103 And your editted code does not contain the line `// ignore any remaining input
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` that I put in my answer. That's (probably) why it isn't working. You need to understand how C++ input and output really works. It's not difficult, it's prefectly logical, it's just the beginners make assumptions that are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // variables
    int width;
    int length;
    char again; // to hold y or n input
    do {
        cout << "Enter length of rectangle";
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Enter width of rectangle";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "The area of the rectangle is" << length * width;
        cout << "The perimeter of the rectangle is" << (length * length) * (width * width);

        // Asks user if they want to play again
        cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n):";
        cin >> again;

        if (again == 'n') {
            cout << "Press any key to continue";
        }

    } while (again == 'y');
}
```

In the code above, I have added a loop that will allow the user to go back to the start when entering 'y'. 
Also, you can't use (else if) without using (if) first.

Conclusion, simply add a loop that will send the user back to the beginning like shown above.

I hope this helps :)